# jquery default checked box selector

Tags: jquery

how do can target or  select the default checked boxes i have written my code on js fiddle
an on the checked default apply a border on load

```
<input id="Male" type="radio" checked="checked"/>M<input id="Female" type="radio" />F</td>
    </tr>
 <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" checked="checked"/><label for="Checkbox1">Widgets</label><br />
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Fx7Cm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use :checked selector

```
$('input:checked')
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Fx7Cm/8/)

Comment: buddy i want only the boxes that a checked to have a border an the radio icon an the check box in ur care ur targeting the entire thing i am new to stack

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your question, but to get the checkboxes that are checked by default, you can [use the attribute selector `[checked]`](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/):

```
$('input[type=checkbox][checked]')
```

Answer (score 0):

You did `$("form :checked")` in your jsfiddle, since there is no form element in your demo, selector `"form :checked"` will hit nothing.

`$(":checked")` will get the checked element in your demo.

And you apply the css property `border` to the input element, which does not have effect.
You could apply to the label after the input.

**[See the working demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Fx7Cm/5/)**

Comment: thanks xdazz cheers :D an also but is there a way where the you can apply a border to the square box checked an the radio circle

Comment: an also but is there a way where the you can apply a border to the square box checked an the radio circle